# Pushing and comparing elements within a vector appears to go out of range for some inputs and not others

Tags: c++, vector

Another question for my own personal understanding and development, not homework etc.

I have spent the best part of 2 - 3 hours coding a little game that has the user guess a series of 4 digit numbers that are then stored within a vector and compared against the hard-coded 'answer' vector. If the user gets a digit and also the place of the number correct, they will receive the output '1 bull', if they enter the correct number but in the wrong place, they will receive the output 'one cow'. If all 4 numbers are guessed correct, they will see '4 bulls' and the input will end.

This works for most inputs, however there are some troublesome ones such as '1 2 6 4' that causes one of the vectors to throw an out_of_range error but i cannot suss out why as I am not trying to access any element beyond the 3rd.

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<int> answers{ 1, 2, 3, 4 };
    std::vector<int> guesses{};
    
    compare(answers, guesses);

}

void compare(std::vector<int> answers, std::vector<int> guess)
{
    int bull{ 0 };
    int cow{ 0 };
    int input{};

    while (bull != 4)
    {
        bull = 0;
        cow = 0;

        for (int i{}; i < answers.size(); ++i)
        {
            std::cin >> input;
            guess.push_back(input);
        }

        for (int first{}; first < answers.size(); ++first)
        {
            for (int second{ 0 }; second < answers.size(); ++second)
            {
                if (answers[first] == guess[first])
                {
                    ++bull;
                    ++first;
                }
                else if (answers[first] == guess[second])
                    ++cow;
            }
        }
        guess.clear();

        std::cout << bull << " bull and " << cow << " cow\n";
    }
}
```

Can anyone spot why this may be happening?

Comment: Hint: ask yourself, how do you know that `guess[first]` from `if (answers[first] == guess[first])` is valid?

Comment: `++first;` inside the inner loop goes past the end of the vectors. Use the debugger.

Comment: *I am not trying to access any element beyond the 3rd.* -- You may not be trying, but you did access those elements.  That's the whole point of debugging -- yes, you expected not to do "x", but you did "x" anyway, so figure out why "x" happened.